# How to implement my own search filter - Django?

Tags: python, django, filter

I have a **Book** model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    ...
```

**HTML form:**

```
<form type="get" action=".">
    <input id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Search..." >
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

For example:
User input some text in my form:"Some strange text"
I wanna find all books, which contain at least one of these words in upper or lower case or some phrases in this text('Some', 'some', 'Strange', 'strange', 'Text', 'text' or 'some strange', 'Strange text' and so on).
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have the text of the book in a field in your model? That is, in the database? Or do you want to search only in the book titles?

Comment: The 'text' I mean book title. And yes, it is

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to search by "or-ing" the individual words of the input? So the text may contain "some" *or* "strang" *or* "text" (ignoring case)?

Comment: Yep, if I enter 'cafe', it should find books like 'The why cafe', 'Cafe number 233'...

Comment: Then Willem's answer, using Q objects being or-ed together, should address your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the search query to obtain the words, and then match these with the title of the book. We can do this by constructing a [**`Q`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) that will represent the filter condition:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = request.GET.get('search_box')
books = Book.objects.all()
if query:
    query = query.split()
    q_obj = Q(
        *[Q(('title__icontains', item)) for item in query],
        _connector=Q.OR
    )
    books = Book.objects.filter(q_obj)
```

If the search box is filled in, it will filter the `books` queryset, such that it contains at least one word of the query.

Comment: What is Q in the example?

Comment: Besides, what is the difference between contain and icontain?

Comment: @СтопчакОлег: `Q` is an object to present a query-part for filtering. `icontains` will match case insensitive, whereas `contains` will match case sensitive.